# Htaccess automatically redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this URL

```
www.domain.com/a.php
```

What I want is

1). I access that using

```
www.domain.com/a_newname
```

2). If somebody gets to know the PHP file and tries accessing it, then too he needs to go the new url (the a_newname) one.

How do I even begin writing htaccess for it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you can use following code

```
Redirect /a.php /a_newname
```